# Javascript run function inside multiple divs with the same class but different variables

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, multiple-instances

I'm trying to run the same function inside multiple container divs with the same class on scroll.

I need to calculate different values for each container and use them on that specific function. The thing is that I need to use classes and I don't know how many containers each page is going to have.

This is my html:

```
   <div class="div-container container">
      <div class="div-inside"></div>
      <div class="div-inside-2"></div>
      <div class="div-inside"></div>
      <div class="div-inside-2"></div>
   </div>
    

   <div class="div-container container">
      <div class="div-inside"></div>
      <div class="div-inside-2"></div>
      <div class="div-inside"></div>
      <div class="div-inside-2"></div>
   </div>

    
   <div class="div-container container">
      <div class="div-inside"></div>
      <div class="div-inside-2"></div>
      <div class="div-inside"></div>
      <div class="div-inside-2"></div>
   </div>
```

And this is what I'm trying

```
var p1 = document.getElementsByClassName('div-inside')

    function moveDivinside() {

      const divcont = document.querySelectorAll('.div-container')
      divcont.forEach(element => {

        let marginWintop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top; 
        let winHeight = window.innerHeight;
        let difference = winHeight - (winHeight - marginWintop);

                let p1n;
                for (p1n = 0; p1n < p1.length; p1n++) {
                    p1[p1n].style.top = difference * .09 + 'px';
                }
        });
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(moveDivinside)
    }, false)
```

It seems it's only getting data from last container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to slightly change your code:

```js
// this line needs to go: 
// var p1 = document.getElementsByClassName('div-inside')
function moveDivinside() {
  const divcont = document.querySelectorAll('.div-container');
  divcont.forEach(element => {
    // you need to select the elements inside the current element
    var p1 = element.getElementsByClassName('div-inside');

    let marginWinTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    let winHeight = window.innerHeight;
    let difference = winHeight - (winHeight - marginWinTop);

    let p1n;
    for (p1n = 0; p1n < p1.length; p1n++) {
      p1[p1n].style.top = difference * 0.09 + 'px';
    }
  });
}
```